# Lines to polygons error in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error

I was using lines to polygons tool and I encountered the following error:
"One or more line ignored due to geometry not having a minimum of three vertices."

[image]

I'm really confused because it worked perfectly in December. Did anyone encounter that error too and has a solution for this?

@EDIT. 
It actually does work in QGIS 2.18. I assume it's because the contours of the smallest "chunks" I created in QGIS 3.4 are actually triangles (see above), whereas when I carried out the same operations in QGIS 2.18 I got squares, so QGIS was able to create polygons from them.

[image]

Comment: Just tried on QGIS 2.18. Works fine for me

Comment: So your line data simply has some non-circular features in it, either not correctly closed polygons or simple lines. Clean up your data if this error irks you very much. Otherwise work with the output given.

Comment: Can you please attach a graphic that particularly shows your problem. I assume you trying to point at two dots on the right side of your image, is not it? Then the error description says precisely "geometry not having a minimum of three vertices", looks like a line is having only start and ending point. You should clean your shapefile, ignoring all the lines with vertices amount less or equal "2".

Comment: Taras, thanks for your answers. I actually opened the project in QGIS 2.18 and it really works there. Simple solutions are usually the best! Thanks again :)