# "One or more line ignored due to geometry not having a minimum of three vertices" error when "Line to Polygon" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, qgis-processing, linestring, geometry-conversion

Converting "Line to Polygons" using geometry tools in Vector could not be executed results shows this picture

[image]

How to solve this issues?

Comment: All of the error messages are saying the lines in question don't have 3 or more vertices. That is, they are being interpreted as straight lines between two points. It is not possible to define a polygon with just two points. If you check your data and think the lines in question do have more than 2 points then there might be another problem I can't identify. In this case, perhaps it would be helpful to share your data.

Comment: Normal, you need three vertices per line for the conversion.  Either add them or chose skip in the settings.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
v

Answer (score 3):

I could get the same error [*"One or more line ignored due to geometry not having a minimum of three vertices"*](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/LinesToPolygons.py#L90) when I was trying to apply the ["Lines to polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgislinestopolygons) geoalgorithm for these polylines:

[image: input]

Every above linestring consists only of two vertices. One can comprehend it for instance with the ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices).

[image: vertices]

So, now there is a pair of only two points (start and end) for each linestring feature. Therefore just two vertices per a linestring makes it impossible to use the desired geoalogirhtm.

A suggestion is to apply the ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) geoalgorithm to merge linestring into a line/polyline. (Keep in mind that either ["Collect geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#collect-geometries) or ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) won't work in this case.)

And after the result of the "Lines to polygons" tool will be much more feasible:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [wikipedia | Polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain)
- [Lines to polygons error in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308524/lines-to-polygons-error-in-qgis)
- [How to transform Linestring to Polyline?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247483/how-to-transform-linestring-to-polyline)